# SQuirreL not displaying "Sources" tab

Tags: squirrel-sql, squirrel.windows, squirrel

I'm running SQuirreL 4.6.0, and I want to be able to see the "Sources" tab after I connect to my host.

I tried installing the latest JARs in my SQuirreL folder, but that did not resolve this issue.

It should be on the far right after "Supported Refactorings"